# Accessing associative arrays in bash script

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I've two bash scripts, one containing two arrays where the values of the first array are the keys for the second array. In another script i need to call a external script with each value of the first array and the value for that key from the second array.

First (config) script:

```
#! /bin/bash

PROC[0]="sshd"
PROC_PID[sshd]="/var/run/sshd.pid"

PROC[1]="openvpn"
PROC_PID[openvpn]="/var/run/openvpn.server.pid"
```

Second script:

```
#! /bin/bash
. ./config

for proc in ${PROC[@]}
do
    echo "$proc";
    echo "$PROC_PID[$proc]";
    /call/to/external/script $proc $PROC_PID[$proc]
done
```

When calling the second script i get this output:

```
sshd
/var/run/openvpn.pid[sshd]
....
openvpn
/var/run/openvpn.pid[openvpn]
....
```

I just cannot figure out, how to access the value from the PROC_PID array associated with a key from the PROC array. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first script you should declare your variables as associative arrays:

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -A PROC PROC_PID

PROC[0]="sshd"
PROC_PID[sshd]="/var/run/sshd.pid"

PROC[1]="openvpn"
PROC_PID[openvpn]="/var/run/openvpn.server.pid"
```

And in your second script you need to use the braces properly. And quote your variables too.

```
#! /bin/bash
. ./config

for proc in "${PROC[@]}"
do
    echo "$proc";
    echo "${PROC_PID[$proc]}";
    /call/to/external/script "$proc" "${PROC_PID[$proc]}"
done
```

Comment: @NoIdea Please check.

Comment: After declaring the arrays everything works. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: It could have actually been simpler as well with just `for proc in "${!PROC_PID[@]}"` but I'm not sure if the expansion would be in order. With that you could have just used one variable. No need for index arrays. You're welcome by the way.

Answer (score 1):

That's how you [get data from associative arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#getting_values):

```
echo "${PROC_PID[$proc]}"
/call/to/external/script $proc "${PROC_PID[$proc]}"
```

And here is your script with correct quoting:

```
for proc in "${PROC[@]}"
do
    echo "$proc"
    echo "${PROC_PID[$proc]}"
    /call/to/external/script "$proc" "${PROC_PID[$proc]}"
done
```

Also you can do

```
PROC[0]='sshd'
PROC_PID[${PROC[0]}]='/var/run/sshd.pid'
```

And this is valid as well:

```
PROC[0]='sshd'
PROC_PID[PROC[0]]='/var/run/sshd.pid'
```

Comment: Executing our example i got theis output:

    sshd
    /var/run/openvpn.pid
    ./40-processes: line 9: ${$PROC_PID[$proc]}: bad substitution

(line 9 is the call to the external script)

okay, the second $ is too much

Comment: But with this approach i still access the value for "openvpn" in the PROC_PID array.